# Does F# documentation have a way to search for functions by their types?

Tags: search, documentation, f#, types

Say I want to know if F# has a library function of type

```
('T -> bool) -> 'T list -> int
```

ie, something that counts how many items of a list that a function returns true for. (or returns the index of the first item that returns true)

I used to use the big list at the MSR site for F# before the documentation on MSDN was ready. I could just search the page for the above text because the types were listed. But now the MSDN documentation only lists types on the individual pages--the module page is a mush of descriptive text. Google kinda-sorta works, but it can't help with

```
// compatible interfaces
('T -> bool) -> Seq<'T> -> int
// argument-swaps
Seq<'T> -> ('T -> bool) -> int
// type-variable names
('a -> bool) -> Seq<'a> -> int
// wrappers
('a -> bool) -> 'a list -> option<int>
// uncurried versions
('T -> bool) * 'T list -> int
// .NET generic syntax
('T -> bool) -> List<'T> -> int
// methods
List<'T> member : ('T -> bool) -> int
```

Haskell has a standalone program for this called [Hoogle](http://www.haskell.org/hoogle). Does F# have an equivalent, like Fing or something?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Based on kvb's answer, I created a complete application. It's hosted on github at http://github.com/sandersn/fing.

The code is still pretty ugly, but it works for simple cases. I took out kvb's most-general-unifier (`mgu`) for now because it adds a lot of non-obvious results. Fancy things like structural constraints and most-general-supertype don't work yet either.

There's also binary for a command-line version if you don't want to build from source. (It still requires a modern version of the .NET runtime installed, though.) Eventually I will find some ASP.NET hosting, learn ASP, and wrap the whole thing in a web app so that no installation is needed at all. (I guess if there is demand I could create a client-side GUI, but I have even less experience with that kind of thing.)

Answer (score 17):

I don't know of any such tool.  However it might be a fun exercise to write one using `System.Reflection` (or even better, the Metadata library in the PowerPack), so that you could take equivalence modulo type variable names, etc. into account.

**EDIT** - I was right - it *was* a fun exercise.  What follows has a lot of warts, but isn't too bad for ~150 lines of code.  Hopefully this will be enough to get someone started who wants to work on a real tool.  It doesn't do anything advanced like checking for functions with reordered parameters, and the Metadata library is a bit picky about using fully qualified names so you need to be a bit careful.  To answer the question in your original post, I executed

```
find "('a -> Microsoft.FSharp.Core.bool) -> Microsoft.FSharp.Collections.list`1<'a> -> Microsoft.FSharp.Core.int"
```

and got the following list of candidates:

```
Microsoft.FSharp.Core.Operators.( + )
Microsoft.FSharp.Core.Operators.( - )
Microsoft.FSharp.Core.Operators.( * )
Microsoft.FSharp.Core.Operators.( / )
Microsoft.FSharp.Core.Operators.( % )
Microsoft.FSharp.Core.Operators.sqrt
Microsoft.FSharp.Core.LanguagePrimitives.EnumOfValue
Microsoft.FSharp.Core.LanguagePrimitives.EnumToValue
Microsoft.FSharp.Core.LanguagePrimitives.AdditionDynamic
Microsoft.FSharp.Core.LanguagePrimitives.CheckedAdditionDynamic
Microsoft.FSharp.Core.LanguagePrimitives.MultiplyDynamic
Microsoft.FSharp.Core.LanguagePrimitives.CheckedMultiplyDynamic
Microsoft.FSharp.Core.LanguagePrimitives.GenericZero
Microsoft.FSharp.Core.LanguagePrimitives.GenericOne
Microsoft.FSharp.Collections.List.find
Microsoft.FSharp.Collections.List.findIndex
Microsoft.FSharp.Collections.List.maxBy
Microsoft.FSharp.Collections.List.minBy
```

Of these, only `List.findIndex` has exactly the generic type you're looking for, but with the right combination of type parameters so do the others (e.g. if `'a = int` then `List.find` has the desired type).  Unfortunately, constraints aren't taken into account in the search so the non-`List` functions can't actually match.

Without further ado, here's the code I used - you'll need to add a reference to the FSharp.PowerPack.Metadata assembly to get it to work.

```
open Microsoft.FSharp.Metadata
open System.Text.RegularExpressions

(* type parameters let us switch out representation if need be *)
type Tag<'ty> = | Tuple | Arr | Ground of 'ty
type Ty<'ty,'a> = Param of 'a | Complex of Tag<'ty> * Ty<'ty,'a> list

(* Gets something stable from an FSharpEntity so that we can see if two are identical *)
let rec getType (e:FSharpEntity) =
  if (e.IsAbbreviation) then
    getType e.AbbreviatedType.NamedEntity
  else
    e.ReflectionType

(* FSharpType -> Ty<System.Type,string> *)
let rec cvt (e:FSharpType) =
  if e.IsTuple then
    Complex(Tuple, e.GenericArguments |> Seq.map cvt |> List.ofSeq)
  elif e.IsFunction then
    Complex(Arr, e.GenericArguments |> Seq.map cvt |> List.ofSeq)
  elif e.IsGenericParameter then
    Param e.GenericParameter.Name
  else
    Complex(Ground(e.NamedEntity |> getType), e.GenericArguments |> Seq.map cvt |> List.ofSeq)

(* substitute type for variable within another type *)
let rec subst v t = function
| Complex(tag,l) -> Complex(tag, l |> List.map (subst v t))
| Param i when i = v -> t
| Param j -> Param j

(* get type variables used in a type *)
let rec usedVars = function
| Param i -> Set.singleton i
| Complex(tag, l) -> Set.unionMany (List.map usedVars l)

(* Find most general unifier (if any) for two types *)
let mgu t1 t2 =
  let rec mgu subs = function
  | [] -> Some subs
  | (Complex(tag1,l1),Complex(tag2,l2))::rest ->
       if tag1 <> tag2 then
         None
       else
         let rec loop r = function
         | [],[] -> mgu subs r
         | [],_ | _,[] -> None
         | x::xs, y::ys -> loop ((x,y)::r) (xs,ys)
         loop rest (l1,l2)
  | (Param i, Param j)::rest when i = j -> mgu subs rest
  | ((Param i, x) | (x, Param i))::rest ->
       if (Set.contains i (usedVars x)) then
         None (* type would be infinite when unifying *)
       else
         mgu ((i,x)::subs) (rest |> List.map (fun (t1,t2) -> (subst i x t1, subst i x t2)))
  mgu [] [t1,t2]

(* Active patterns for parsing - this is ugly... *)
let (|StartsWith|_|) r s =
  let m = Regex.Match(s, r)
  if m.Success && m.Index = 0 then
    Some(m.Value, s.Substring(m.Length))
  else None

let rec (|Any|) (|P|_|) = function
| P(x,Any (|P|_|) (l,r)) -> x::l, r
| s -> [],s

let rec (|Any1|_|) (|P|_|) = function
| P(x,Any (|P|_|) (l,r)) -> Some(x::l, r)
| _ -> None

let (|Seq|_|) (|P|_|) (|Q|_|) = function
| P(x,Q(y,r)) -> Some((x,y),r)
| _ -> None

let (|Choice|_|) (|P|_|) (|Q|_|) = function
| P(p) -> Some p
| Q(p) -> Some p
| _ -> None

let (|Delimit|_|) s (|P|_|) = function
| P(x,Any ((|Seq|_|) ((|StartsWith|_|) s) (|P|_|)) (l,r)) -> Some(x::(List.map snd l), r)
| _ -> None

let (|Delimit1|_|) s (|P|_|) = function
| P(x,StartsWith s (_,Delimit s (|P|_|) (l,r))) -> Some(x::l, r)
| _ -> None

(* Basically a BNF grammar for types *)
let rec (|TyE|_|) = function
| ArrE(p) | TupleE(p) | AtomE(p) -> Some(p)
| _ -> None
and (|ArrE|_|) = function
| Choice (|TupleE|_|) (|AtomE|_|) (dom,StartsWith "->" (_,TyE(rng,r))) -> Some(Complex(Arr,[dom;rng]), r)
| _ -> None
and (|TupleE|_|) = function
| Delimit1 @"\*" (|AtomE|_|) (l,r) -> Some(Complex(Tuple,l), r)
| _ -> None
and (|AtomE|_|) = function
| ParamE(x,r) | GroundE(x,r) | StartsWith @"\(" (_,TyE(x,StartsWith @"\)" (_,r))) -> Some(x,r)
| _ -> None
and (|ParamE|_|) = function
| StartsWith "'[a-zA-Z0-9]+" (s,r) -> Some(Param s, r)
| _ -> None
and (|GroundE|_|) = function
| StartsWith "[`.a-zA-Z0-9]+" (gnd, StartsWith "<" (_, Delimit "," (|TyE|_|) (l, StartsWith ">" (_,r)))) -> 
      let ty = FSharpAssembly.FSharpLibrary.GetEntity gnd |> getType
      Some(Complex(Ground(ty), l), r)
| StartsWith "[`.a-zA-Z0-9]+" (gnd, r) ->
      let ty = FSharpAssembly.FSharpLibrary.GetEntity gnd |> getType
      Some(Complex(Ground(ty), []), r)
| _ -> None

(* parse a string into a type *)
let parse (s:string) =
  (* remove whitespace before matching *)
  match s.Replace(" ","") with
  | TyE(ty,"") -> ty
  | _ -> failwith "Not a well-formed type"

(* an infinite stream of possible variable names - for performing renaming *)
let rec names = 
  let letters = ['a' .. 'z'] |> List.map string
  seq {
    yield! letters
    for n in names do
      for l in letters do
        yield n + l
  }

(* finds entities in the F# library with the requested signature, modulo type parameter unification *)
let find s =
  let ty = parse s
  let vars = usedVars ty
  seq {
    for e in FSharpAssembly.FSharpLibrary.Entities do
    for m in e.MembersOrValues do
      (* need try/catch to avoid error on weird types like "[]`1" *)
      match (try Some(cvt m.Type) with _ -> None) with
      | Some ty2 ->
        (* rename all type variables from the query to avoid incorrectly unifying with type variables in signatures *)
        let used = usedVars ty2
        let newVars = Seq.choose (fun v -> if Set.contains v used then None else Some(Param v)) names
        let varMap = Map.ofSeq (Seq.zip vars newVars)
        let ty = Map.fold (fun t v p -> subst v p t) ty varMap
        match mgu ty ty2 with
        | None -> ()
        | Some _ -> yield sprintf "%s.%s.%s" e.Namespace e.DisplayName m.DisplayName 
      | _ -> () }
```

Comment: Thanks, this looks great. When I have time I'll try to work this into something as usable as Hoogle.

Answer (score 5):

This is the latest and greatest: http://fsdn.azurewebsites.net/

From the docs: https://github.com/fsdn-projects/FSDN

> Supported API signatures
>
> ```
> API signature                     Query example
> Functions and values in modules   int -> string
> Fields of records and structs     Ref<'a> => 'a
> Methods and properties            'a list -> int or 'a list => int
> Constructors                      string -> Uri
> Names (function and method names) head : 'a list -> 'a
> Active patterns                   (||) : ... -> Expr -> ?
> ```

Answer (score 0):

I've created a tool I call Typle (https://typle.net) that allows you to search all packages published on nuget.org for a specific (F#) type signature.

I try to handle "argument-swaps", "uncurried versions", "type-variable names" and "methods" from your list.

Currently only ".NET generic syntax" is the only syntax supported for generics.