# Upgrading FParsec: upgrade discriminated unions to satisfy the new equality/comparison constraints

Tags: f#, constraints, discriminated-union

So, by a [hi*lar*ious series of events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2253730/does-f-documentation-have-a-way-to-search-for-functions-by-their-types), I downloaded the FParsec source and tried to build it. Unfortunately, it's not compatible with the new 1.9.9.9. I fixed the easy problems, but there are a couple of discriminated unions that still don't work.

Specifically, [Don Syme's post](http://blogs.msdn.com/dsyme/archive/2009/11/08/equality-and-comparison-constraints-in-f-1-9-7.aspx) explains that discriminated unions containing items of type `obj` or `->` don't automatically get equality or comparison constraints, since objects don't support comparison and functions don't support equality either. (It's not clear whether the automatically generated equality/comparison was buggy before, but the code won't even compile now that they're no longer generated.)

Here are some examples of the problematic DUs:

```
type PrecedenceParserOp<'a,'u'> =
     | PrefixOp of string * Parser<unit,'u> * int * bool * ('a -> 'a)
     | others ...

type ErrorMessage =
     | ...
     | OtherError of obj
     | ...
```

Here are the offending uses:

```
member t.RemoveOperator (op: PrecedenceParserOp<'a, 'u>) =
    // some code ...
    if top.OriginalOp <> op then false // requires equality constraint
    // etc etc ...
```

or, for the comparison constraint

```
let rec printMessages (pos: Pos) (msgs: ErrorMessage list) ind =
    // other code ...
    for msg in Set.ofList msgs do // iterate over ordered unique messages
        // etc etc ...
```

As far I can tell, Don's solution of tagging each instance with a unique int is the Right Way to implement a custom equality/comparison constraint (or a maybe a unique int tuple so that individual branches of the DU can be ordered). But this is inconvenient for the user of the DU. Now, construction of the DU requires calling a function to get the next stamp.

Is there some way to hide the tag-getting and present the same constructors to users of the library? That is, to change the implementation without changing the interface? This is especially important because it appears (from what I understand of the code) that `PrecedenceParserOp` is a public type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What source did you download for FParsec? I grabbed the latest from the FParsec [BitBucket repository](http://bitbucket.org/fparsec/main/), and I didn't have to make any changes at all to the FParsec source to get it to compile in VS 2010 RC.

Edit: I take that back. I did get build errors from the InterpLexYacc and InterpFParsec sample projects, but the core FParsec and FParsecCS projects build just fine.

Comment: I downloaded the latest official release from 2009-02-26, so I'll give the latest source a try--I forgot about the 'outdated' warning on the page by the time I ran into problems.

Comment: Those build errors in the sample projects are just from missing a reference to FSharp.PowerPack.Compatibility, too. It's easy to fix.

Answer (score 1):

One thing you could do is add `[<CustomEquality>]` and `[<CustomComparison>]` attributes and define your own `.Equals` override and `IComparable` implementation.  Of course, this would require you to handle the `obj` and `_ -> _` components yourself in an appropriate way, which may or may not be possible.  If you can control what's being passed into the `OtherError` constructor, you ought to be able to make this work for the `ErrorMessage` type by downcasting the `obj` to a type which is itself structurally comparable.  However, the `PrecendenceParserOp` case is a bit trickier - you might be able to get by with using reference equality on the function components as long as you don't need comparison as well.

Comment: Do functions support reference equality? I can't tell that they do, but that *would* solve the problem. As for `OtherError`, good idea, I'll check the uses of `OtherError` to see if I can downcast.

Comment: Bad news: One of [Brian's posts](http://lorgonblog.spaces.live.com/blog/cns!701679AD17B6D310!1621.entry) links to the [precise part of the spec](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/cambridge/projects/fsharp/manual/spec.html#_Toc245030880) that says that functions do not support reference equality. Well, it's "under-defined", meaning I guess that the method is there but returns nonsense.

Comment: @Nathan - it's not that it returns nonsense so much as that the compiler's current behavior should not be assumed to be forward compatible.  Although it would be a bit of a hack to rely on it, it's pretty easy to check that at the moment functions stored in a DU can be successfully tested for identity using `obj.ReferenceEquals`.  I think that the rule is likely in place to emphasize that there are no guarantees as to how something like `(fun x -> x + 1) = (fun x -> x + 1)` will be evaluated.  Having said all that, if you can find a cleaner solution by all means use it.