# Does F# have pursuit or hoogle?

Tags: f#

I saw recently that some code (Fake, specifically) uses a function `@@` without defining it, presumeably it exists as part of the F# standard library, or somewhere else in .NET.

How do I search online for this type? Is there a [pursuit](https://pursuit.purescript.org/)-like or [hoogle](https://hoogle.haskell.org/)-like  database I can use?

---

This question focuses more on *how* to find a particular function, and incidentally, `hoogle` alternatives.  There are two very good answers, and the nature of the answers and comments are quite different.

Comment: See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/fsharp/language-reference/symbol-and-operator-reference/

Comment: @Mankarse: That particular function isn't there, and misses the question.

Comment: F# doesn't **yet** have anything like Pursuit or Hoogle, AFAIK. Some people have been discussing something like that (see discussion on https://github.com/fsharp/FAKE/issues/1485, for example), but nobody has done it yet. It will be a big improvement if/when it finally happens, and there are no technical reasons why it couldn't happen, just a lack of time among the many people (like me) who want to see it happen.

Comment: @rmunn: That's unfortunate - thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2253730/does-f-documentation-have-a-way-to-search-for-functions-by-their-types?rq=1

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does F# documentation have a way to search for functions by their types?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2253730/does-f-documentation-have-a-way-to-search-for-functions-by-their-types)

Comment: Note that tooling such as Visual Studio and Visual Studio Code will show the fully qualified name, type signature and documentation on mouse hover for operators. Not helpful on GitHub, though.

Comment: @TheQuickBrownFox: And not helpful in .fsx files,  either, unless I'm mistaken?

Comment: This works in FSX files too as long as the dependencies are in place. They are just as statically typed as FS.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is [FSDN](http://fsdn.azurewebsites.net/) that allows hoogle-like searching in mscorlib, some System.* dlls and a few libraries (including FAKE).

**Update** 2022-06-11: FSDN seems to be offline. I don’t know an alternative.

Comment: This, together with rmunn's comment that there isn't actually anything like pursuit or hoogle, is the answer I was after *especially* w.r.t. FAKE #1485 which rmunnlinked.

FSDN itself seems to be the closest we have today.

Comment: As of 2017/05/17 19:00 JST, FSDN has been added FAKE APIs support (thanks to FSDN guys!). So, check `FAKE.Lib` item in the Target Assemblies menu (right side of the page), input `(@@) : _`, and then you'll get the signature of the `@@` function.

Answer (score 6):

It's defined under `Fake.EnvironmentHelper` module ([source](https://github.com/fsharp/FAKE/blob/master/src/app/FakeLib/EnvironmentHelper.fs#L26)):

```
let inline (@@) path1 path2 = combinePaths path1 path2
```

where `combinePaths` is just a curried form of the BCL's `Path.Combine` with removal to leading path seperator in `path2` ([source](https://github.com/fsharp/FAKE/blob/master/src/app/FakeLib/EnvironmentHelper.fs#L21)):

```
let inline combinePaths path1 (path2 : string) = 
    Path.Combine(path1, path2.TrimStart [| '\\'; '/' |])
```

Note that `Fake.EnvironmentHelper` has the [`AutoOpenAttribute`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualfsharpdocs/conceptual/core.autoopenattribute-class-%5Bfsharp%5D) applied to it. Other modules referring to this `@@` operator do not need to explicitly `open` the `Fake.EnvironmentHelper` module.

Comment: That explains it!  Particularly for the AutoOpenAttribute attribute.  However, if you consider the `@@` to be an example, does F# have an equivalent for pursuit, or hoogle, etc?

Comment: The only F# search engine similar to Hoogle is the MSDN, which is the link to the `AutoOpenAttribute` in my answer.

Comment: MSDN is a fairly... Crap search engine if comparing to hoogle or pursuit, but if that's what we have, then that's what we have (until someone fixes it).  I'll accept your answer as a result - thanks.

Comment: I haven't had much experience with Haskell so I cannot compare but one thing I quite like about MSDN is they provide examples to almost all library functions, which is quite useful, especially to newcomers of functional programming.

Comment: The best thing about hoogle, is that you can literally search by generic types.  Eg, `(a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]`, which is map.  It's a great way to determine "Has someone implemented this before?", and critically, can search for weird symbols such as `https://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=%3E%3D%3E`

Comment: Searching on type signature is less useful than in Haskell since F# is not pure (there are many possible implementations of `'a -> 'a` with different side-effects) and less generic. This may be why less effort has gone into this.

Comment: @TheQuickBrownFox: Fair point, though I would hope that utilities, such as `@@` in the case of Fake and operators in general would be pure.

Answer (score 0):

I've created a tool I call Typle (https://typle.net) that allows you to search all packages published on nuget.org for a specific (F#) type signature.